# Alternative to mrouted for DVMRP on Debian Squeeze

Tags: networking, ip, routing, multicast

I need to implement DVMRP protocol to route multicast over Openvpn (tun) connection for some old 3Com NBX phones.

I use Debian squeeze so mrouted is not available (obsolete).

What can I use instead?

Comment: You could, in a pinch, see if the old package still works: http://archive.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/m/mrouted/

Comment: https://github.com/troglobit/mrouted also has a `debian` directory, so possibly the package can be compiled from that source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some search I found this: http://freecode.com/projects/mrouted

I downloaded the latest source code (2011) and it compiled flawlessly on 64-bit cpu.

Thank you all anyway!

Comment: Huh, always great to see my hard work being put to good use :)